# Sketch the solution to a second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am asked to solve a second order differential equation to solve with two initial conditions.

> $6y'' - 5y' +y = 0$
>
> $y(0)=4$
>
> $y'(0)= 0$

I have the solution which is...

> $y = 12e^{\frac{1}{3}x} - 8e^{\frac{1}{2}x}$

But the second portion of the question is asking to sketch the solution. I'm drawing a complete blank on this.

Graphing calculators aren't allowed on tests, so I need to see how it can be done by hand. Thanks.

Comment: There is a critical point at $(0,4)$ which turns out to be a maximum using the first derivative test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that $y\to0^+$ as $x\to-\infty$. You know that $y=4$ at $x=0$ and if you solve

$$ 12e^{\frac{1}{3}x} - 8e^{\frac{1}{2}x}=0$$

you get $y=0$ at $x=6\ln\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)\approx2.4$.

If you set

$$y^\prime=4e^{\frac{1}{3}x} - 4e^{\frac{1}{2}x}=0$$

you find that $x=0$ so the point $(0,4)$ is actually a maximum point of the graph.

This is enough information to sketch a convincing graph. Be sure to label the coordinates.

In other words try to find asymptotes, intercepts and max/min points using techniques you learned in calculus.